# How to create a custom view for TextView and change text dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin

The scenario I'd like to reproduce is :

Having a textView with a drawable left with a green text color (also the tint of the drawable) when tap on that `TextView` then change the color of the text and change the start drawable (also the tint of the drawable) that is shown for 5 seconds, once these 5 seconds have passed with a fade in/fade out animation change back to the initial state.

I've started creating a custom view

```
class MyCustomTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
) : ConstraintLayout(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
) {

    fun onClickToCopy(){
        //Add the animation to the new state
        coroutineScope.launch {
            delay(5_000L)
        }
        //With an animation come back to the initial state
    }

}
```

But now I'm stuck I don't know how to proceed with this, do I have to create an `init{}` with the initial state ?

Comment: Instead of creating a custom text view, why don't u try using a combination of image view and text view. You will have more control on their properties this way.

Comment: Is to have everything on a single place : The animation, the logic, etc... what option you propose? Could you put an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give a rough idea, you can do something like this:

```xml
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:layout_width="40dp"
          android:tint="@color/green"/>
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView"
          android:textColor="@color/green"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your Activity/Fragment:

```kotlin
textView.setOnClickListener {
    textView.textColor = // New color
    imageView.imageResource = // New image
    imageView.tint = // New tint
    // For the delay you can use a normal Handler
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
        {
            // Animate these changes however you wish
            textView.textColor = // Original color
            imageView.imageResource = // Original image
            imageView.tint = // Original tint
        }, 
        5_000 // 5 sec delay
    )
}
```

(I don't remember all the properties so might have used some wrong property names here, but this should give you the general idea)

For the fade in/out part, you can use the common view animation apis. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800716/android-fade-view-in-and-out) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796139/fade-in-fade-out-android-animation-in-java) SO threads to get some idea on how to animate views.

Comment: I tries to explain the basic approach here. If you have any doubts regarding this, feel free to comment. I will update the answer accordingly.